# DB Collation required for Intersystems Cache (1280 or 1251

Tags: database, internationalization, collation, intersystems-cache

Guys i am looking for collation Latin Cyrillic may be having code 1280 or 1251 
I am asking this since one of the DB Systems i am using is not ready to open the file and read the contents since the collation is not installed.

I use a windows XP pro.

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need clarification

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that you are getting a  error when trying to access the database?

You'll have to go in and create your own nls table, the rough steps are:
* copy current table
* edit the new one: add the translation tables you need to the io tables
* activate the new one

Depending on the Version of Cache you're running this is doable in the management portal. (also via d ^%NLS in terminal, but it's much more cumbersome there)